# How to decrease ps aux output to a few lines?

Tags: linux, process, output

When my computer is slowing down, I usually run `ps aux --sort -rss` to find out which process consumes too much memory. There may be a lot of processes. How to see only a few ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [tell `ps` to sort its output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71932/how-to-decrease-ps-aux-output-to-a-few-lines/71935#71935). But this seems to be a use case for [top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(Unix)) or [htop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop_(Unix)). Press `M` to sort processes by  memory and `P` to sort by CPU time.

Comment: thank you. It's much simpler than `ps -eo pid,command,pcpu,pmem --sort -rss | head -N` (N is the number of processes I'd like to see.

Answer (score 4):

`ps aux --sort -rss | head` would seem to be the best bet. `head` with no argument will display the first 10 lines of its standard input (which would mean the `ps` column headers, followed by the first 9 processes as returned by your `ps` command). To see a different number of processes, call `head -n <n>` where `<n>` is the number of lines you want.

Comment: I tested the command you had given. It printed names of the processes with all their arguments as a string. It would quite suit me if I didn't use `head`. `head` made the table unreadable. I used `ps -eo pid,command,pcpu,pmem --sort -rss | head -5` (to see 5 processes).

Comment: `head` prints on its standard output what it reads on its standard input - it's all strings. Show us what you got, and what you want, and perhaps we can get you closer.

Comment: Drop the `-e` flag on `ps`. It causes `ps` to print each process's environment, which is *not* what you show in the "I want" image.

Comment: I don't understand you. I print all the processes and decrease the output with `head`. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: Stop using the `-e` option to `ps`. It is that option that is causing you to get all the additional information that you say you don't want.